# How Can make a zombie process in linux shell which is not killed by Ctrl-C?

Tags: linux, shell, zombie-process

How Can make a zombie process in linux shell which is not killed by Ctrl-C and makes a copy of itself before dying? if it's possible, How would we ever kill such a process?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: Just handle SIGINT (the default handler is to kill the process). You would be able to kill it with `kill -9` which means "[nuke it from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a zombie process has already *died*. It's not consuming any resources beyond the entry in the process table. The process that spawned it either neglected the bookkeeping of `wait`ing for it or setting ignore on `SIGCHLD` before `fork`ing. Since it has already exited, `kill` has no effect on a zombie process (nor will `kill -9`). It will *only* be removed from the process table when its parent calls `waitpid()` or exits.

If you just want your script to ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or `kill`, use `trap "code" SIGNALS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo Not dead yet!" SIGINT SIGTERM
echo "Kill me with kill -9 $$"
while true; do sleep 1; done
```